# Eclipse: Save files without asking when I click run

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to save files without asking in Eclipse? Every time I click Run, it asks me if I want to save the file, and I always do.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-17.htm

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Preferences > Run/Debug > Launching.

There's a setting called "Save required dirty editors before launching". Set it to "Always".

Answer (score 6):

There should be a check box on that Save File dialog:[image: Eclipse Save Prompt on Run]

Comment: I just installed Eclipse and I don't have a checkbox, else I would have checked it. :(

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
,
Version: Helios Service Release 2 ,
Build id: 20110218-0911

Answer (score 2):

Or you can choose the option in Window->Preferences->General->Workspace and check the option called "Save automatically before build". This would make your life definitely easier

Answer (score 0):

You can select the `Automatically save resources` checkbox the next time it prompts but I believe that's a per project setting.