# Save Resource Dialog in Eclipse pops up while editing a java file.

Tags: java, eclipse, egit

I'm running into an annoying problem in Eclipse. Sometimes as I'm in the middle of typing out a change in java code, Eclipse's "Save Resource" dialog keeps popping up, telling me that it has detected a change and wants to know if I want to save the change. It used to be I'd only get this prompt if I closed a modified file and did not save. Now I get it as I'm in the process of editing a file. I'm not sure if it's a problem with Eclipse, with the EGit plugin or something else all together.

I'm currently running Eclipse Indigo (3.7.1), with EGit 1.3.0.201202151440-r).

Also I'm not able to easily upgrade either of these products as they are running on a system that is not connected to the internet and are withing a corporate lan with a complex process to get updates to software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from a similar, but different, question: [Eclipse: Save files without asking when I click run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669784/eclipse-save-files-without-asking-when-i-click-run)

The option that was causing this problem was found in the setting located at:

```
Window->Preferences->Run/Debug->Launching
```

Inside of this view was the option "Save required dirty editors before launching." My selection was set to prompt.

It turns out I had some executable in my workspace that would trigger on a change.